# CATextLayer ignores font-size

Tags: swift, uiimageview, catextlayer

I would like to create an overlay of text to my images. The problem is, if ill try to add a second text, like a subtitle it ignores my font-size.

```
    titleLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, imageView.bounds.width, 50)
    subTitleLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 130, imageView.bounds.width, 40)

    titleLayer.string = "Title"
    subTitleLayer.string = "Subtitle"


    let fontName: CFStringRef = "HelveticaNeue"
    let fontSubName: CFStringRef = "HelveticaNeue-Thin"
    titleLayer.font = CTFontCreateWithName(fontName, 16, nil)
    subTitleLayer.font = CTFontCreateWithName(fontSubName, 10, nil) // Ignores the font-size

    imageView.layer.addSublayer(titleLayer)
    imageView.layer.addSublayer(subTitleLayer)
```

The new font is correct, but its always with the same size (16) like the titleFont. How can i change the font size?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Have a look at this note on [font property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATextLayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CATextLayer/font) of CATextLayer

> If the font property is a CTFontRef, a CGFontRef, or an instance
>   of NSFont, the font size of the property is ignored.

It clearly explain that font size of CTFontRef is ignored. To solve your problem you have to explicitly set `fontSize` attribute of CATextLayer

```
titleLayer.fontSize = 16
subTitleLayer.fontSize = 10
```

Comment: Thank you very much Zell B. I got this issue the whole afternoon. That interface is really "dangerous" from Apple. It's really slippy, I got caught and never thaught that I must copy the font size into another property...